# Android testing against the release version of an app

Tags: android-testing, android-espresso

What is the correct way to run Espresso tests against the release version of my app?

1. If I change the build variant to release,
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" disappears from the
   "Specific instrumentation runner" list of the "Run/Build
   configurations". The error is "Cannot resolve symbol 'runner'".
2. If I try to run tests without the debug version of the app installed I am
   getting the "Unable to find instrumentation target package" error.

Can anybody help me, please?